# android: using arrayadapter<Custom object> that was created in AsyncTask in the MainActivity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, return-value, android-arrayadapter

I got the following problem and hope someone could give me a hint.

I have an activity that executes an `AsyncTask< String, Void, ArrayList<Custom object >>`.
In the `doInBackground()` function, I set up a new `ArrayList` of custom objects which is also the return value.
In the `onPostExecute()` method that `ArrayList` is used in a newly created `ArrayAdapter<Custom object>`, which is also set to a `ListView` with `lv.setAdapter(adapter).`
so far so good!

now the thing is: back in the MainActivity I will need that adapter again, cause I wanna add new items to it by calling `adapter.add(items).`
for now I had the `AsyncTask` as an inner class of my MainActivity and could use the same `ListView` & the same `ArrayAdapter,` that worked very well!

but because I have another class which needs to execute that `AsyncTask` too, I changed that inner class `AsyncTask` to a standalone `.java` file (`CustomAsyncTask.java`)

-> now when I try to add new items to the `ArrayAdapter` it throws a `NullPointerException!`
of course that is, cause the `ArrayAdapter` belongs to the `AsyncTask` and is created there
so I tried to give the `ListView` and the `ArrayAdapter` from the MainActivity as a parameter for the `CustomAsyncTask` constructor to use it in there
but that did not work, the `ArrayAdapter` in MainActivity is always null causing the Exception

any ideas how to solve that?
I would really appreciate it.

here the code of the MainActivity.java:

```java
// global variables
ArrayAdapter<Custom object> arrayadapter;
ListView listview;
ProgressBar progressbar;

...

protected void myMethod() {
    CustomAsyncTask hTask = new CustomAsyncTask(this, listview, progressbar, arrayadapter);
    hTaskPlaylist.execute(String sth);
}

...

protected void anotherMethod() {
    arrayadapter.add(item);
}
```

and the code of CustomAsyncTask.java:

```java
package com.mypackage.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Custom object>>{

    Context context;
    ListView listview;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    ArrayAdapter<Custom object> arrayadapter;

    public CustomAsyncTask(Context con, ListView lv, ProgressBar pb, ArrayAdapter<Custom object> aa) {
        this.context = con;
        this.listview = lv;
        this.progressbar = pb;
        this.arrayadapter = aa;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        listview.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Custom object> doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<Custom object> list = new ArrayList<Custom object>();

            ... doing something and populating list
            return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Custom object> list) {
        super.onPostExecute(list);

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Custom object>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

        progressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                listview.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your ArrayAdapter static.. Then anytime you want to access it you can simply say CustomAsyncTask.arrayadapter.add(items); You are also allowed to add your own functions to your custom asynctask class. You could create something like public ArrayAdapter<> getAdapter().  But careful, you are going to have multiple threads accessing/changing that object regardless, so it would be a good idea to synchronize access.

You could try something like this...

```
ArrayAdapter globalAdapter;
globalAdapter = new CustomAsyncTask().execute(/*your parameters here*/).get();
```

Comment: thank you.. but isn't there a way to return the value back to MainActivity (not just in onPostExecute())?-> 'cause it works when the AsyncTask is an inner class of the MainActivity, somehow it should work if it is an external class too, shouldn't it`?

Comment: Was the adapter originally a variable in the main activity? because inner classes have access to the outer class's instance variables... And yes it should work to have your async task return an array adapter; however, any changes you make to that returned value will not persist for other instances.

Comment: the ArrayAdapter arrayadapter is defined globally in the MainActivity (so when Activity starts the adapter is null), then I create a new AsyncTask object with the arrayadapter & listview as a parameter and execute it.

in the CustomAsyncTask I populate the listview with the arrayadapter, which was filled with an arraylist. (in onPostExecute())

the listview that also comes from the MainActivity is correctly set, only when I try to call arrayadapter.add(item) it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: Well they are not global if they are declared in your activity, because global would mean all classes and subclasses have access to them. When you give the arrayadapter to the AsyncTask, it is passed by value.. meaning that any changes you make to that arrayadapter will not affect the one that is in your main activity.

Comment: sry, with globally I meant for the class MainActivity.
but how is it to explain that I can work with the passed listview in MainActivity AND AsyncTask
isn't it some kind of strange that JAVA handles object by reference, but when passing method arguments its by value?
so is there a way to pass in the arrayadapter by reference?

Comment: Java only allows by value.  What you can do, is have your AsyncTask return an ArrayAdapter and then assign it to your "global" variable. See code edit above ^

Comment: I've already tried the .get() function of AsyncTask object, but that's pretty uncomfortable, cause it blocks the UI thread
and then I've also tried in the onItemClick() method of the listviev to get the assigned adapter by calling adapterview.getAdapter().add (parameter of onItemClick) but that didn't work either

Comment: That's true. well could you just give your AsyncTask an arrayadapter as an attribute? then the asynctask modifies its own adapter. Then you can set your global adapter to the value of the task's adapter. otherwise if the user isn't doing anything anyways, you could use a process dialog on the main thread or something.

Comment: goingto try, and how 'bout some kind of callback method to inform the MainActivity and passing the ArrayAdapter to it when it is not null?

Comment: well, you could create a constructor for your AsyncTask and give it an instance of the parent activity. Then your task could call a function in the main activity when it finishes loading the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Now I tried that and pass the `MainActivity` as a parameter instead of the `Context`,
here is what I changed:

```
public class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Custom object>>{

    **MainActivity activity**;
    ListView listview;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    ArrayAdapter<Custom object> arrayadapter;

    public CustomAsyncTask(**MainActivity act**, ListView lv, ProgressBar pb, ArrayAdapter<Custom object> aa) {
        **this.activity = act;**
        this.listview = lv;
        this.progressbar = pb;
        this.arrayadapter = aa;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Custom object> list) {
        super.onPostExecute(list);

        arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Custom object>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        **activity.arrayadapter = arrayadapter;**

        progressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        listview.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Yeah, it worked!
Thank you Joel,
but I'm still wondering why I can pass `listview` from `MainActivity`, call a function on that listview in `AsyncTask` and normally work with that listview back in `MainActivity`, any ideas?

And another question: is it right, that the only difference in passing an `Activity` object instead of a `Context` object, is you're having access to the available variables and methods you defined in your `Activity`?

Comment: You're welcome!  When you pass listview to the AsyncTask, the task is given a copy of the listview that is in your activity.  So it can do whatever it wants with that listview and it will not change the one in your activity.  And yes, that is essentially it.  With a context, you never really know what kind of object that is a representation of.  If you want, you can cast a context as an instance of your activity by doing 'MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;' and then you have full access to any functions in the MainActivity class!

Comment: But it will throw a null pointer exception if you try and cast a context that is not an instance of your activity.

Comment: after what you said, am I right in assuming that Context is generally superfluous or am I missing sth?

Comment: Kind of... for example, in a call such as Toast.makeText(this,...); where this refers to an activity. activity is actually a subclass of context, so you can pass it as a context argument like in the make text method. Context is ambiguous, and has several subclasses. so if you have an instance of context, it also likely secretly an instance of one of its subclasses (such as activity). Maybe read the developer notes on context if you think that might help